# Cleanly remove NPM-installed executable

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have an executable that's installed with npm globally:

```
npm install -g r2g
```

I uninstall it:

```
npm uninstall -g r2g
```

but a phantom executable still exists, if I run `r2g`.

However, when I run `$(which r2g)` it's empty. So maybe it's in the bash hash?

When I run:

```
hash -p r2g
```

I get something strange:

```
$ hash -p r2g
hits    command
   3    /Users/alexamil/.nvm/versions/node/v10.1.0/bin/npm
   4    /bin/rm
```

how can I completely remove an executable installed globally with NPM?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't what you wanted, but you could use a multistage build, then you won't have to remove build dependencies https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/. So ideally you'd install r2g in the first stage, use it, then move on to the next stage where you would only install what's needed to run your application.

Answer (score 0):

When you run:
$ npm uninstall -g r2g 
The module will be removed but not the dependencies.

Remove it globally by running:
$ npm -g uninstall r2g --save